# Unable to login to facebook using fbchat

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a python program to send fb message but unable to login using the following code...

```
import fbchat 
from getpass import getpass

username = input("username: ")
client = fbchat.Client(username, getpass())
print(client.getSessions)
no_of_friends = 1 #int(("Number of friends: ")) 

for i in range(no_of_friends): 
    
    name = str(input("Name: "))
    
    friends = client.searchForUsers(name)  # return a list of names
    
    friend = friends[0]
    
    msg = input("Message: ") 
    
    sent = client.send(fbchat.models.Message( msg), thread_id = int(friend.uid))
    
    if sent: 
        
        print("Message sent successfully!")
```

It gives the following error...

```
Attempt #1 failed, retrying
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fbchat/_client.py", line 205, in login
    self._state = State.login(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fbchat/_state.py", line 151, in login
    return cls.from_session(session=session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fbchat/_state.py", line 190, in from_session
    revision = int(r.text.split('"client_revision":', 1)[1].split(",", 1)[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: That sounds like a bug report for the maintainer of that library…

Answer (score 0):

*Try this one , I have tested it , works perfectly.You need to add the User agent.*

```
import fbchat
import re
fbchat._util.USER_AGENTS    = ["Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36"]
fbchat._state.FB_DTSG_REGEX = re.compile(r'"name":"fb_dtsg","value":"(.*?)"')
from getpass import getpass 
username = str(input("Username: ")) 
client = fbchat.Client(username, getpass()) 
no_of_friends = int(input("Number of friends: ")) 

for i in range(no_of_friends): 
    name = str(input("Name: ")) 
    friends = client.searchForUsers(name) # return a list of names 
    friend = friends[0] 
    msg = str(input("Message: ")) 
    sent = client.send(fbchat.models.Message( msg), thread_id = int(friend.uid)) 
    if sent: 
        print("Message sent successfully!")
```

Comment: How to send a message in Facebook using messenger using Python fbchat ?